# Subsets in subsets without looping in R

Tags: r, subset, vectorization

this is my starting data:

```
days <- c("01.01.2018","01.01.2018","01.01.2018","01.01.2018",
          "02.01.2018","02.01.2018","02.01.2018","02.01.2018",
          "03.01.2018","03.01.2018","03.01.2018","03.01.2018")
time <- c("00:00:00","08:00:00","12:00:00","16:00:00",
          "00:00:00","08:00:00","12:00:00","16:00:00",
          "00:00:00","08:00:00","12:00:00","16:00:00")
a <- c(10,12,11,14,
       12,22,24,20,
       11,8,13,16)
b <- c(18,22,26,21,
       2,6,7,5,
       27,31,29,26)
c <- a-b
d <- c(10,10,10,10,
       20,20,20,20,
       30,30,30,30)

df <- data.frame(days,time,a,b,c,d)
```

so `df` will come out as:

```
         days     time  a  b   c  d
1  01.01.2018 00:00:00 10 18  -8 10
2  01.01.2018 08:00:00 12 22 -10 10
3  01.01.2018 12:00:00 11 26 -15 10
4  01.01.2018 16:00:00 14 21  -7 10
5  02.01.2018 00:00:00 12  2  10 20
6  02.01.2018 08:00:00 22  6  16 20
7  02.01.2018 12:00:00 24  7  17 20
8  02.01.2018 16:00:00 20  5  15 20
9  03.01.2018 00:00:00 11 27 -16 30
10 03.01.2018 08:00:00  8 31 -23 30
11 03.01.2018 12:00:00 13 29 -16 30
12 03.01.2018 16:00:00 16 26 -10 30
```

in this dataframe i'd like to

- for each day
- find the first `c` value `<-10`
- add the corresponding `d` values to ranges from the `c` value found before and the last `c` value of the day

this is what i've come up:

```
ndays <- unique(df$days)
for(i in 1:length(ndays)) {
  if(!is.na(df[(df$days == ndays[i] & df$c <= -10),]$c[1]))
  {
    df[(df$days == ndays[i] & df$c <= -10),]$c <- df[(df$days == ndays[i] & df$c <= -10),]$c + df[(df$days == ndays[i] & df$c <= -10),]$d
  }
}
```

Output will be:

```
         days     time  a  b  c  d
1  01.01.2018 00:00:00 10 18 -8 10
2  01.01.2018 08:00:00 12 22  0 10
3  01.01.2018 12:00:00 11 26 -5 10
4  01.01.2018 16:00:00 14 21 -7 10
5  02.01.2018 00:00:00 12  2 10 20
6  02.01.2018 08:00:00 22  6 16 20
7  02.01.2018 12:00:00 24  7 17 20
8  02.01.2018 16:00:00 20  5 15 20
9  03.01.2018 00:00:00 11 27 14 30
10 03.01.2018 08:00:00  8 31  7 30
11 03.01.2018 12:00:00 13 29 14 30
12 03.01.2018 16:00:00 16 26 20 30
```

Problem is, i'd like not to use a for loop since is slow, and is not adding `d` to the entire day. `df$c[4]` should be `3`.

Comment: By your own needs, *df$c[4] should be 3* is not true as it is the last value of the day.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using `dplyr` and `lubridate`. I'm not  100% sure to understand what you want to do, but I think it should help you to solve your problem.

```r
days <- c("01.01.2018","01.01.2018","01.01.2018","01.01.2018",
          "02.01.2018","02.01.2018","02.01.2018","02.01.2018",
          "03.01.2018","03.01.2018","03.01.2018","03.01.2018")
time <- c("00:00:00","08:00:00","12:00:00","16:00:00",
          "00:00:00","08:00:00","12:00:00","16:00:00",
          "00:00:00","08:00:00","12:00:00","16:00:00")
a <- c(10,12,11,14,
       12,22,24,20,
       11,8,13,16)
b <- c(18,22,26,21,
       2,6,7,5,
       27,31,29,26)
c <- a-b
d <- c(10,10,10,10,
       20,20,20,20,
       30,30,30,30)
```

By creating a variable `yday` with `lubridate` functions, you can after group by this variable.You can use cumulative maximum  `cummax`.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(yday = day(dmy(days))) %>% 
  mutate(is_below = c < -10) %>% 
  group_by(yday) %>% 
  mutate(to_add =  cummax(is_below)) %>% 
  mutate(c = if_else(to_add ==  1, true = c + d, false = c))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 9
#> # Groups:   yday [3]
#>          days     time     a     b     c     d  yday is_below to_add
#>        <fctr>   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>    <lgl>  <int>
#>  1 01.01.2018 00:00:00    10    18    -8    10     1    FALSE      0
#>  2 01.01.2018 08:00:00    12    22   -10    10     1    FALSE      0
#>  3 01.01.2018 12:00:00    11    26    -5    10     1     TRUE      1
#>  4 01.01.2018 16:00:00    14    21     3    10     1    FALSE      1
#>  5 02.01.2018 00:00:00    12     2    10    20     2    FALSE      0
#>  6 02.01.2018 08:00:00    22     6    16    20     2    FALSE      0
#>  7 02.01.2018 12:00:00    24     7    17    20     2    FALSE      0
#>  8 02.01.2018 16:00:00    20     5    15    20     2    FALSE      0
#>  9 03.01.2018 00:00:00    11    27    14    30     3     TRUE      1
#> 10 03.01.2018 08:00:00     8    31     7    30     3     TRUE      1
#> 11 03.01.2018 12:00:00    13    29    14    30     3     TRUE      1
#> 12 03.01.2018 16:00:00    16    26    20    30     3    FALSE      1
```